# Sequentially change a link color and then change it back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I've been playing around with the following code I've written to show/hide the top menu on my website, nothing impressive here. However what I'm trying to accomplish (and failing miserably at) is sequentially making each link change to this bright blue and then change back to white. I'm trying to add / remove my current state class in order to achieve the color change. But it's obviously not working, what's happening is the class gets added to all the links immediately and then never removed..

So ideally Link 1, then 2, then 3, etc. would all flash blue and then after a few milliseconds one after another each would change back to white.

Below is my jQuery code..

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($){
$( '#menuIcon' ).on('click', function(e){
    $( this ).toggleClass('active');
    $( '#primaryMenu' ).toggleClass('active');

    if( $( '#primaryMenu' ).hasClass('active') ){
        $('#primaryMenu > li').each(function(i) {
            $(this).delay((i++) * 200).addClass( 'current-menu-item' );
            $(this).delay((i++) * 300).removeClass( 'current-menu-item' );
        })
    }
});

<ul class="trans5 active" id="primaryMenu">
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-77 current-menu-item" id="menu-item-77"><a href="http://example.com">Link 1</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-71 current-menu-item" id="menu-item-71"><a href="http://example.com">Link 2</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-92 current-menu-item" id="menu-item-92"><a href="http://example.com">Link 3</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-91 current-menu-item" id="menu-item-91"><a href="http://example.com">Link 4</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-90 current-menu-item" id="menu-item-90"><a href="http://example.com">Link 5</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-95 current-menu-item" id="menu-item-95"><a href="http://example.com">Link 6</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-76 current-menu-item" id="menu-item-76"><a href="http://example.com">Link 7</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-80 current-menu-item" id="menu-item-80"><a href="http://example.com">Link 8</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="menuIcon" title="Show Menu" class="trans5">
<div class="one trans2"></div>
<div class="two trans2"></div>
<div class="three trans2"></div>
</div>
```

[image: Here is my top menu]

Comment: Added the menu markup! :)

Comment: Where is the element with id "menuIcon" ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think it would be of any use so I left it out. I've added it in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/) in the wrong way. jQuery's `delay` is used for queuing effects, and `addClass` is not considered an effect. Use [queue](https://api.jquery.com/queue/) to queue a method instead. Like so:

```js
var inDelay = 100;
var outDelay = 200;

$( '#menuIcon' ).on('click', function(e){
  
    $('.menu-item').each( function(i){
      
      $(this).delay(inDelay * i).queue( function () {
        
        $(this).addClass('current-menu-item').dequeue().delay(outDelay).queue( function () {

          $(this).removeClass('current-menu-item').dequeue();
        
        });
      });
    });
});
```

```css
body { text-align: left; }
ul { padding: 0; }
.menu-item { display: inline-block; background-color: black; padding: .1em .25em; }
.menu-item a { color: white; text-decoration: none; transition: color .5s; }
.menu-item.current-menu-item a { color: blue; }
#menuIcon { display: inline-block; color: white; background-color: green; cursor: pointer; padding: .1em .25em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="trans5 active" id="primaryMenu">
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-77" id="menu-item-77"><a href="http://example.com">Link 1</a></li><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-71" id="menu-item-71"><a href="http://example.com">Link 2</a></li><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-92" id="menu-item-92"><a href="http://example.com">Link 3</a></li><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-91" id="menu-item-91"><a href="http://example.com">Link 4</a></li><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-90" id="menu-item-90"><a href="http://example.com">Link 5</a></li><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-95" id="menu-item-95"><a href="http://example.com">Link 6</a></li><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-76" id="menu-item-76"><a href="http://example.com">Link 7</a></li><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-80" id="menu-item-80"><a href="http://example.com">Link 8</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="menuIcon" title="Show Menu" class="trans5">
  Show Menu
</div>
```

Comment: Great answer, you're the best! :)